# Web.config messing with Symfony Controllers

Tags: php, git, symfony, azure

I have two azure servers one is running code of my master branch from git hub and the second (dev server) is running off the code from my master side branch (i do know that i can use /app_dev.php but im choosing this way cause i prefer it)

basically the step i was taking was adding web.config (ill paste it below) to protect access to my web folder and so that when the URL  was hit it would return the front controller instead of having to do the following

heres the web.config file

```
<!-- web.config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="BlockAccessToPublic" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/web/*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteAssetsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="web/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteRequestsToPublic" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="web/app.php/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

if you go here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html

and scroll to the very bottom, it talks about it. i do apolgise im not very good at explaining myself.

im confused because on the Dev server its returning a twig template saying my project is ready to be started at etc etc, but on the prod server, where the web.config has not been merged and the url is domain/web/app.php  it is retunring the controller and templates that i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your description, you had 2 Azure Web Apps services hosting dev and prod symphony applications. If I have any misunderstanding, please point out it.

In my test, after finishing deployment symphony application on Azure Web Apps as the answer to your last question. I just copy the content of `app_dev.php` on local and overwrite the `app.php` on cloud.

And I comment the code used to check whether the server is localhost, which is:

`if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}`

Then browse `http://<your-website-name>.azurewebsites.net`, it works fine.

So please check your deployment steps, it should be the same with the steps of your success one.

If you have  an on-premise `web.config` in your local  project and deploy it on Azure Web app with the application. It seems will raise an internal error in my test. You can try the following steps to fix this issue:

1. Login in the Kudu Console of your site, and delete the existing
   `web.config` file in your site root directory.
2. Create a new one with the command: `touch web.config`
3. Click the pencil icon to edit the file, copy the content on
   http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html#configure-the-web-server
   to it.
4. Restart your site.